# How to iterate over a Pandas DataFrame based on some condition to create a new DateFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have imported a csv file to a Pandas DataFrame with sales pipeline data. Each line represents an ooportunity with prospect name, product info, pipeline stage, probabiility, expected deal size, expected closing date, duration, etc.

Now I would like to convert this to a sales forecast, whereby I want to calculate the average revenue per period by dividing the dealsize through the duration times the probability. And then create a line for all possible period based on the expected closing date and the duration.

I have create a simplified example to support my question:

```
import pandas as pd

pipeline_data = [{'Client': 'A', 'Stage': 'suspect', 'Probability': '0.25', 'Dealsize': '1200', 'Duration': 6, 'Start_period': '2020-08'}, {'Client': 'B', 'Stage': 'prospect', 'Probability': '0.60', 'Dealsize': '1000', 'Duration': 4, 'Start_period': '2020-10'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(pipeline_data)
df
```

Output:

```
    Client  Stage    Probability Dealsize   Duration    Start_period
0   A       suspect  0.25        1200       6           2020-08
1   B       prospect 0.60        1000       4           2020-10
```

So the average revenue per month for Client is 1200 / 6 * 0.25 = 50. And the revenue would fall in the periods 2020-08 - 2021-01 (so from August 2020 until January 2021).

The preferred output would be:

```
    Client  Stage    Probability Dealsize   Duration    Start_period Weighted_revenue Period
0   A       suspect  0.25        1200       6           2020-08      50               2020-08
1   A       suspect  0.25        1200       6           2020-08      50               2020-09
2   A       suspect  0.25        1200       6           2020-08      50               2020-10 
3   A       suspect  0.25        1200       6           2020-08      50               2020-11
4   A       suspect  0.25        1200       6           2020-08      50               2020-12
5   A       suspect  0.25        1200       6           2020-08      50               2021-01
6   B       prospect 0.60        1000       4           2020-10      150              2020-10
7   B       prospect 0.60        1000       4           2020-10      150              2020-11
8   B       prospect 0.60        1000       4           2020-10      150              2020-12
9   B       prospect 0.60        1000       4           2020-10      150              2021-01
```

I already converted the Start_period to Period type so it can be used to calculate/iterate.

I'm pretty new to coding. I've tried to find an answer on this and other sites, but unsuccessful till yet. I can imagine to use some sort of nested looping and append functions to solve this, but I don't know how to use this with Pandas...

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with a list comprehension, `pd.date_range` and `explode`

```
df['Weighted_revenue']=(df['Dealsize'].astype(float)/df['Duration'].astype(float))*df['Probability'].astype(float)
df['Period']=[pd.date_range(x, periods=y, freq="M").strftime('%Y-%m') for x,y in zip(df["Start_period"], df["Duration"])]
df=df.explode('Period')
```

Output:

```
df
  Client     Stage Probability Dealsize  Duration Start_period  Weighted_revenue   Period
0      A   suspect        0.25     1200         6      2020-08              50.0  2020-08
0      A   suspect        0.25     1200         6      2020-08              50.0  2020-09
0      A   suspect        0.25     1200         6      2020-08              50.0  2020-10
0      A   suspect        0.25     1200         6      2020-08              50.0  2020-11
0      A   suspect        0.25     1200         6      2020-08              50.0  2020-12
0      A   suspect        0.25     1200         6      2020-08              50.0  2021-01
1      B  prospect        0.60     1000         4      2020-10             150.0  2020-10
1      B  prospect        0.60     1000         4      2020-10             150.0  2020-11
1      B  prospect        0.60     1000         4      2020-10             150.0  2020-12
1      B  prospect        0.60     1000         4      2020-10             150.0  2021-01
```

---

**Details:**

First we create the `'Weighted_revenue'` column with the formula you have described:

```
df['Weighted_revenue']=(df['Dealsize'].astype(float)/df['Duration'].astype(float))*df['Probability'].astype(float)
df

  Client     Stage Probability Dealsize  Duration Start_period  Weighted_revenue
0      A   suspect        0.25     1200         6      2020-08              50.0
1      B  prospect        0.60     1000         4      2020-10             150.0
```

Then, we use a list comprehension, with `zip`, to create the date range base on the `'Start_period'` and `'Duration'` columns

```
df['Period']=[pd.date_range(x, periods=y, freq="M").strftime('%Y-%m') for x,y in zip(df["Start_period"], df["Duration"])]
df

  Client     Stage Probability Dealsize  Duration Start_period  Weighted_revenue                                             Period
0      A   suspect        0.25     1200         6      2020-08              50.0  [2020-08, 2020-09, 2020-10, 2020-11, 2020-12, 2021-01]
1      B  prospect        0.60     1000         4      2020-10             150.0               [2020-10, 2020-11, 2020-12, 2021-01]
```

And finally we use `explode` to expand the lists:

```
df=df.explode('Period')
df 

 Client     Stage Probability Dealsize  Duration Start_period  Weighted_revenue   Period
0      A   suspect        0.25     1200         6      2020-08              50.0  2020-08
0      A   suspect        0.25     1200         6      2020-08              50.0  2020-09
0      A   suspect        0.25     1200         6      2020-08              50.0  2020-10
0      A   suspect        0.25     1200         6      2020-08              50.0  2020-11
0      A   suspect        0.25     1200         6      2020-08              50.0  2020-12
0      A   suspect        0.25     1200         6      2020-08              50.0  2021-01
1      B  prospect        0.60     1000         4      2020-10             150.0  2020-10
1      B  prospect        0.60     1000         4      2020-10             150.0  2020-11
1      B  prospect        0.60     1000         4      2020-10             150.0  2020-12
1      B  prospect        0.60     1000         4      2020-10             150.0  2021-01
```

Comment: A list comprehension might perform better: `df['Period'] = [pd.date_range(x, periods=y, freq="M").strftime('%Y-%m') for x,y in zip(df["Start_period"], df["Duration"])]`.

Comment: @HenryYik - that's true, since the creation will only consider that two columns, just edited the answer with your suggestion, thank you!

Comment: Thanks all for the swift response, much apprecioated! So much new code I've never heard of... So much to learn. I will try it out and then come back to 'accept'

Comment: With some slight adjustments it works brilliantly on my actual code. Thanks again.

Comment: You´re welcome @Frank0013 ! Nice first question on the site +1 :), also remember in next times to add what you have tried, even if it was a for loop or something like that.

Comment: Will do that! Cheers